# Add Date Time to XML via XSLT1

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following shortened XSLT script.
In row 7 I have the code to show the date time. I understand that this solution is for XSLT2 whereas I use XSLT1. Thats why I get an error. I could not find any working solution for XSLT1. Could someone please assist how to add the date and time to a XML file.

> <xsl:value-of  select="current-dateTime()"/>

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="resultset">
    <products>
        <timestamp><xsl:value-of  select="current-dateTime()"/></timestamp>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </products>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What is your XSLT processor?

Comment: How do you call your XSLT? Which XSLT engine are you using? For example if you are calling it using a script (batch, etc.), you could simply passe the current date-time as a paramater when calling the command.

Comment: It seems the EXSLT site is down currently but some XSLT 1.0 processors like Xalan or libxslt/xsltproc support EXSLT date/time functions, see e.g. Xalan's documentation https://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/apidocs/org/apache/xalan/lib/ExsltDatetime.html.

Comment: @Sebastien I am using a script. Would you have any example how to pass the info on.